# Running python on Ipython real time or on scheduled basis

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a python code that outputs charts and process reports on the console. The results can be saved to html and saved.
Question: I need it to run on a scheduled bases and save the results to html. How to?

Comment: Set a cron job. Or make an infinite loop, where the last line is to sleep until the next schedule.

Comment: Okay about the cronjob but my question is more about schecduling the Ipython.